# Adjusting Fill style behavior using QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

How can I change the Fill style option in QGIS?

I need to use a diagonal pattern that does exist, but I need to adjust it. I have a cartography specification that defines the diagonal pattern to have a specific angle, line width and distance between diagonal lines.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the **Line pattern fill** to set your diagonal lines with defined angles and distance between lines.

[image: Line fill pattern]

To edit the width of the line, select the **Line** layer:

[image: Line properties]